# I am new to React and trying to make a form using useState. I get an error: "TypeError: setValues is not a function handleInputChange"

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import {Grid, TextField} from "@material-ui/core"

const initialFieldValues = {
    sName: ''
}

const StudentForm = (props) => {
    const {values, setValues} = useState(initialFieldValues)

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const {name,value} = e.target
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value

        })
    }

    return (
        <form autoComplete = "off" noValidate>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item={6}>
                    <TextField
                        name = "sName"
                        variant = "outlined"
                        label = "Full Name"
                        value = {values.sName}
                        onChange = {handleInputChange}
                    />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </form>
    )
}

export default StudentForm
```

Comment: it should be `const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues)`

Comment: Typo, should use square brackets, i.e. array destructuring: `const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues)`

Answer (score 2):

you have to use square brackets with useState().

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong parentheses. Change to square brackets:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

React api `useState` hook will return an `array` which you can destructure its `value` and `setValue` function like this:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import {Grid, TextField} from "@material-ui/core"

const initialFieldValues = {
    sName: ''
}

const StudentForm = (props) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues) // change {} to []

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const {name,value} = e.target
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value

        })
    }

    return (
        <form autoComplete = "off" noValidate>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item={6}>
                    <TextField
                        name = "sName"
                        variant = "outlined"
                        label = "Full Name"
                        value = {values.sName}
                        onChange = {handleInputChange}
                    />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </form>
    )
}

export default StudentForm
```